# Extension vectors in an array in a VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, adder, binary

Given :

```
type data_array is array (integer range 0 to (N- 1))  of std_logic_vector ( ( M-1 ) downto 0);
signal data: data_array     := (others => (others => '0'));
```

I am going to sum all vector up.

```
for i in 0 to 3 loop
  adder_sum <= signed(data(4*k)) + signed(data(4*k + 1))+ signed(data(4*k + 2)) ;
end loop;
```

I need to extend each vector. How to do it?

I have tried:

```
for i in 0 to N-1 loop
  data (i) <= data(i) (M-l) & data(i) ; -- L additional bits
end loop;
```

Comment: If you're going to treat them as integers, why do you not just use an array of integers?

Comment: @DonFusili could you give an example? I dont understand your point

Comment: You only need to extend one "+" operand here (the leftmost, operators of the same precedence use left to right order or parentheses) the shorter operand is sign extended (and synthesis tools know how to implement std_logic_arith, "+" uses resize). The sum is the length of the longest operand. The resize *function* in package numeric_std gotchi85 relates sign extends an expression of type signed and is synthesis eligible. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 1):

You can use resize command.

Here an example on a std_logic_vector signal which has signed represented values inside

`data_out_32b <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(data_in_16b),32));`

Comment: In VHDL I can use `resize`, but it can be used ( compiled) in a hardware.

Comment: You mean it can't be used in hardware? Which device are you using?

Comment: I am using Minized. I would like to cut data(i). Example, If data(i) is range 0 to 10, i need range 1 to 9

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the issue completely by using higher abstraction data types.

```
type data_array is array (integer range 0 to yourlength)  of integer range 0 to whatever;
signal data: data_array := (others => 0);
```

Which can be accumulated in any other integer

```
for i in 0 to yourlength loop
  sum <= sum + data(i);
end loop;
```

without superfluous casting and transformations. Bonus is that this will even simulate faster.

Comment: ok, I can do it.  But I would like to cut `data(i)`. Example,  If `data(i)` is `range 0 to 10`, i need range 1 to 9`

Comment: @LenaPark Then write that. It's not like it will save you LUTs or gates unless it's taken to extremes, but there's nothing stopping you from changing numbers in your code.

Comment: If I use your suggestion, I need to convert to integer `data`...I would like to work only with `std_logic_vector`. ` data` is a resultant of a previous operation.